# How do you disable the Windows Phone 7 splash screen?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, splash-screen

Is there any way to disable the WP7 splash screen and just show a blank screen?

My splash screen only stays on for less than half a second, leaving the user with a rather jarring sensation.  I'd rather they not see any splash screen at all.

I would have simply used a plain black image as my splash screen, but then that would result in an ugly experience for people using a light theme (since my app's background is white on light themes and black on dark themes)

Thanks!

Comment: This question would fit better on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: You could somehow integrate your splashscreen with your initial page - perhaps providing some animation when your app is first shown to make the experience less jarring. Alternatively, I believe that most users (by a long way) use the dark theme - so you could design around that?

Comment: nebukadnezzar - I disagree - this is a programming question - its about an app's splashscreen in WP7, not about the WP7 phone's splashscreen

Comment: @nebukadnezzar - It's an WP7 application development question, why would it fit better on superuser.com?

Comment: @Richard Szalay: My fault, I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply remove the file `SplashScreenImage.jpg`.

Comment: That's not working.  I'm getting the error: 
  Xap packaging failed. Could not find file 'C:\Path\To\App\SplashScreenImage.jpg'. Any idea how to stop this?

Comment: silly question, did you delete the file from your project or just from your disk?

Comment: Silly answer: I just deleted it from disk :P

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the image file, select "Exclude from project". Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to delete the `SplashScreenImage.jpg`as madd0 said :)
If you want your SplashScreen to last longer you can add a start page like this:
[Customer Splash Screen](http://newtonapps.com/post/2010/06/30/Windows-Phone-7-Customized-Splash-Screen-TrickTip.aspx)
Modify the Timespan to suit your the time you want:

> _splashTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone says, you could delete it. But before that, just rename it - right-click on SplashScreenImage.jpg in the Solution Explorer, click rename and just name it something like: SplashScreenImage2.jpg - gives VS a chance to catch up with your intent depending on your machine. Then delete that file.

You can and should delete the splash screen as per the guidance in the [Windows Phone 7 Application Certification Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730558) in section 5.2.1.a:

> Microsoft recommends that the
>   application provides a splash screen
>   image only when it takes longer than 1
>   second to load the first screen.

However, one thing that I've discovered is that while many apps can fire up really fast the first time they are launched, they made load slower after that if they have data that has been tombstoned. Just FYI

Comment: @Zain: this article just came out today. Good read: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-Splash-Screens-in-WP7-ndash-Creating-animated-Splash-Screen